# How to disable auto-complete braces in TEXStudio?

Tags: texstudio, braces, auto-completion

I want to disable auto-complete for braces in TeXstudio. In its simplest form, when I type `{`  I do not want it to automatically add a `}`.  When it does this, many times I end up deleting the brace, which is a hassle.  Also, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to get into italics mode I don't want it to auto-complete the ending brace either.  I have gone to `Options -> Configure TeXstudio... -> Completion -> Show Advanced Options` and disabled everything.  But it still auto-completes them.

In case it matters the version I have is TeXstudio 2.8.4.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are having texworks editor

Comment: haha it's fine.  Part of my problem is all the help out there is for different editors/versions.  I have edited the post to include the version in case it comes up again.

Answer (score 6):

Please uncheck "Auto Complete Parentheses". It can be found "Options / configure TeXStudio" (see screenshot). It does work for me under TeXStudio 2.12.14.
[image: close parentheses automatically]

Edit: as for the shortcut CTRL+I.  I don't think there is an easy way to achieve that. You will have to either alter an existing cwl file (where the definitions are stored) or create a new one. Perhaps you can find an answer when you search for the term "custom cwl".

Comment: Thanks that fixed the first part.  Any idea on how to have it not auto place the close brace when you do "ctrl-i"?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please see above

Comment: K thanks.  Probably not worth the effort then.  But you fixed the main issue I had, so thanks a ton :D

Comment: Question on Ctrl+I: Go to `Macros -> User Macros` and create a new *normal* macro with content `\textit{`. Then go to `Options -> Configure -> Shortcuts` and assign Ctrl+I to your new macro.

Comment: I'd add this as a comment to blue_tiger300's answer but I don't have enough reputation.
I was having the same problem (but on TeXStudio version 2.9.4) and I found before I could find the 'close parentheses automatically' option, I had to tick the 'show advanced options' button in the bottom left of the 'configure TeXStudio' dialogue box.